# SurveyMonkey grant_type password

Tags: surveymonkey

Is it possible to use the grant_type 'password' for SurveyMonkey? Or something similar where no one is actually logging into the system as we are just requesting data and sending it back.

We have a client that wants to use a custom JavaScript-based application on their Intranet that will show users various information and then ask them a series of questions and log their responses for retrieval later.

According to the documentation, users are redirected to the SurveyMonkey website for the OAuth dialog and then can request and send data once they have a valid auth token. But who would this user be? As so far we haven't seen anything in SurveyMonkey regarding users who complete the survey, only admin accounts for who manage them. *Unless we have missed it?*

So is having a different grant type possible with the API?

We'd be interested to see what options we have available to us, as we're finding the documentation over at https://developer.surveymonkey.com/ a bit vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SurveyMonkey only supports the "authorization code" grant type, implicitly stated in the [example code](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/guide_oauth).  Note that we are in the process of updating this OAuth code to give a much broader and detailed picture of how our OAuth works.

You cannot use SurveyMonkey's API to send in responses btw if this is what you were planning on doing - it is a read only API.  You can see the list of supported requests on the left sidebar [here](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_survey_list).

When you complete OAuth, you are given an access token to the user's account who completed OAuth - i.e. you can access all their surveys and responses.

Respondents to a survey do not have an account on SurveyMonkey - they are represented as objects retrieved via the API method [get_respondent_list](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_respondent_list), which accesses a specific survey's respondents.  This survey is one of the surveys belonging to a specific user's account - i.e. the user account that completed OAuth.

Comment: Thanks, that clears up what users and respondents are in SurveyMonkey, and what the API offers. Unfortunately it doesn't look to do what we want.